# Autheticate before redirecting to dashboard

Tags: django

I placed a authentication before displaying a view but when i run it it give this error
TypeError:'bool' object is not callable

user.is_autheticated() not work in django 2.1.5

```
def Login_View(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['pwd']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                data_user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
                request.session['username'] = username
                return render(request,'dashboard_app/index.html',{'data_user':data_user.username})
            else:
                return render(request, 'login_app/index.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'login_app/index.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
    return render(request, 'login_app/index.html')
```

```
def Dashboard_View(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.session.has_key('username'):
            name=request.session['username']
            return render(request, "dashboard_app/index.html",{'name':name})
        else:
            request.session['username'] = User.username
    else:
        return render(request, "Login_app/index.html")
```

I want to authenticate before redirection of page

Comment: Change `if request.user.is_authenticated():` to `if request.user.is_authenticated:`. They changed this from a method to a property.

Comment: this is not not giving previous error but it is also not working. Still redirecting to dashboard without any authentication.```def Dashboard_View(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.session.has_key('username'):
            name=request.session['username']
            return render(request, "dashboard_app/index.html",{'name':name})
        else:
            return render(request, "Login_app/index.html")
    return render(request,'Login_app/index')
```